# Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined

Tags: c++, cmake

I create a `CMakeLists.txt` and the content is as followed

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project(CTP_dll)

add_library(CTPdll SHARED CTPdll.cpp)
add_executable(CTPTest CTPTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CTPTest CTPdll)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(CTPdll ${OpenCV_LIBS})

find_package(VTK REQUIRED)
include(${VTK_USE_FILE})
target_link_libraries(CTPTest ${VTK_LIBRARIES})
```

And the error info is

> CMake Error at D:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/share/hdf5/hdf5-targets.cmake:37 (message):
> Some (but not all) targets in this export set were already defined.

> Targets Defined: hdf5::hdf5-shared;hdf5::hdf5_hl-shared

> Targets not yet defined: hdf5::hdf5_cpp-shared;hdf5::hdf5_hl_cpp-shared

If I delete the including of VTK as followed, no error will be reported. But obvious I can't include `VTK` in `CTPTest.cpp`, which is unacceptable.

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.8)
project(CTP_dll)

add_library(CTPdll SHARED CTPdll.cpp)
add_executable(CTPTest CTPTest.cpp)
target_link_libraries(CTPTest CTPdll)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
include_directories(${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(CTPdll ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

I compile this with Visual Studio 2022 on windows10 platform.
There was a similar question on the web but nobody replied. So I propose this question and hope someone can help.

Comment: "There was a similar question on the web but nobody replied." - it would be very helpful to post the link to that similar question

Comment: did the provided answer help you? if so, please consider upvoting / accepting it. if not, feel free to comment on what aspect ia still unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you are encountering [vcpkg issue #15502](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/issues/15502).

There is a [pull request with a fix available](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/15521/files), [another pull request with a fix is now merged](https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/23352).

Comment: The issue was fixed in PR https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg/pull/23352 btw.